# Using iPhone deviceToken for other purposes after push notification?

Tags: iphone, push-notification, devicetoken

We are using push notification, so we have the deviceToken of the user, we want to use it for doing queries via HTTP Request, so it is sent outsite the phone. I would like to know if is it possibile/regular/legal for Apple using the deviceToken in this purpose.

thanks

Comment: You have to send it outside the phone anyway (you send it to your server, to allow your server to push notifications to the device). It is not clear what else you intend to do with it.

Comment: @Eran - probably as a unique anonymous identifier for that phone.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it an idea to notify the user by **Apple Push Notification**, and then let the app pull the queries via HTTP request after it launches?